# Is there any way to determine what program or service is using a device when I try to eject it?

Tags: windows, usb, usb-storage

[image: Error box]

I keep getting a message like this. How might I debug / troubleshoot why this is being thrown?

Answer (score 1):

[Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) should be able to tell you what files are open, and so you can filter for the files open on the removeable drive.

Go to "Filter/Filter..." in the menu, select `Path` from the dropdown menu, choose `Begins with`, then enter the path for the removable disk in the criteria field.  Make sure Include is selected in the next dropdown, and click `Add`.

Comment: Erm.. how do I do that? It shoes handles but I don't want to go through all 150+ processes and all the files they have open looking....

Comment: I have updated my answer with more detail

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Unlocker](http://www.filehippo.com/download_unlocker/) to look for file locking handles on the device. This program is also very useful for deleting things that Windows won't let you delete. Use with caution; the file was probably locked for a reason at some point (whether that reason is still valid or not, on the other hand...).

Comment: Hmm.. how do I point it at the whole drive? I've used this for nuking files and such before but it doesn't seem to want to look at the whole drive. (This also doesn't work for things that don't expose drives; e.g. phones/ipods/etc.)

Comment: It has added itself to the right-click menu in Windows Explorer on my XP machine. You simply right-click in the drive and choose "Unlocker".

Comment: No such luck on my box. Maybe because it's a 64 bit machine.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Dev Eject](http://deveject.com/). It does exactly what you want. Dev Eject shows you a list of all open files on a drive and the process that is accessing it.